# How can I make a click-through overlay in Rust that still captures input?

Tags: rust, window, user-input, overlay, winit

I already have code that creates a transparent window and draws a square on it using [winit](https://crates.io/crates/winit/0.26.1/dependencies) and [pixels](https://crates.io/crates/pixels), but I can't make it click-through, that is, let the user interact with what is behind the overlay window, while still letting the app capture input. Here's a minimal example of my code:

```rust
use pixels::{wgpu::Color, Pixels, SurfaceTexture};
use winit::{
    event::{DeviceEvent, ElementState, Event, KeyboardInput, VirtualKeyCode, WindowEvent},
    event_loop::EventLoop,
    platform::windows::{WindowExtWindows, HWND},
    window::{WindowBuilder, WindowLevel},
};

fn main() {
    let event_loop = EventLoop::new();
    let window = WindowBuilder::new()
        .with_fullscreen(Some(winit::window::Fullscreen::Borderless(None)))
        .with_transparent(true)
        .build(&event_loop)
        .unwrap();

    window.set_window_level(WindowLevel::AlwaysOnTop);
    window.set_cursor_hittest(false).unwrap();

    let window_size = window.inner_size();
    let surface = SurfaceTexture::new(window_size.width, window_size.height, &window);

    let mut pixels = Pixels::new(window_size.width, window_size.height, surface).unwrap();
    pixels.set_clear_color(Color::TRANSPARENT);

    event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
        control_flow.set_wait();

        match event {
            Event::WindowEvent {
                event: window_event,
                ..
            } => match window_event {
                WindowEvent::KeyboardInput {
                    input:
                        KeyboardInput {
                            virtual_keycode: Some(VirtualKeyCode::Space),
                            state: ElementState::Pressed,
                            ..
                        },
                    ..
                } => {
                    println!("Input from window event");
                }

                WindowEvent::CloseRequested => control_flow.set_exit(),

                _ => (),
            },

            Event::DeviceEvent {
                event:
                    DeviceEvent::Key(KeyboardInput {
                        virtual_keycode: Some(VirtualKeyCode::Space),
                        state: ElementState::Pressed,
                        ..
                    }),
                ..
            } => {
                println!("Input from device event");
            }

            Event::RedrawRequested(_) => {
                pixels.render().unwrap();
            }

            _ => (),
        }
    });
}
```

I thought that `Event::DeviceEvent` would work because it seemed like it wasn't restricted to a specific window, but it is. In every scenario I've tried, both or none of the `println!()`s were called. Do I need another crate for that?

Comment: What do you need this for? It sounds suspiciously like the mouse version of a keylogger.

Comment: @Finomnis Is that why I found it so difficult to find that information online? A friend of mine said it'd be fun to have a program that replicated the League of Legends ping as an overlay. I don't even play the game, but I thought it was a fun way to start learning the language. [My first question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75505017/how-can-i-make-rust-with-the-rodio-crate-load-multiple-sources-in-a-vec-so-i) was a few days ago about playing sound. It's the same project. The sound will be the ping sound.

Comment: It seems that the [device-query](https://crates.io/crates/device_query) can solve the problem. I don't have access to my computer right now, so I'll try it later. But I'd still prefer to do it in winit if possible.

Comment: @Finomnis I respect your suspicion because its true my problem is similar to a keylogger. However, first of all, because of your suspicion I searched for it, and there are simple keyloggers in the top results. Why would I do it myself in Rust? Trying to prevent people from learning how to do malicious stuff on the internet would also prevent self-taught programmers from learning advanced stuff that *could potentally* harm others. That includes most of the things that are not interacting with the terminal. Now let's get extreme: think about ethical hacking. How would that be taught?

Comment: My opinion, though. I'm sure that's not a new discussion. But the truth is that, in programming, you can always get to a malicious result through non-malicious stuff if you really want to. I am new to Rust and creating and handling windows, so I took some time to find my answer because I was not very open-minded about searching for a non-window approach, but it is now solved.

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crate [device_query](https://crates.io/crates/device_query) can solve the problem. It doesn't even need a window to function, as the input is queried on demand by calling `DeviceState::get_keys()` and `DeviceState::mouse()` on a DeviceState instance for keyboard and mouse respectively.

```rust
use device_query::{DeviceState, DeviceQuery};

// Cheaply creates an empty DeviceState
let device_state = DeviceState::new();

// Those methods query the input. They are individualy lazily queried.
let keys = device_state.get_keys();
let mouse = device_state.get_mouse();

let is_alt_pressed = keys.contains(&Keycode::LAlt);
let is_m1_pressed = mouse.button_pressed[1]; // It starts at [1] for M1. [0] has no meaning.
```

The above code can capture input without window focus and even without a window at all. In the code provided in the question, it should be put inside the `MainEventsCleared` event. It is also required to replace `control_flow.set_wait()` in the first line inside the `event_loop.run()` closure with `control_flow.set_poll()`, so that `MainEventsCleared` will always run, even without new events.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `window.set_cursor_hittest(false)` will work although this is [only supported on certain platforms](https://docs.rs/winit/latest/winit/window/struct.Window.html#method.set_cursor_hittest).

Comment: That does allow me to click through the window, but it does not let me read the input. That part was already done in the code of the question, but with an ugly call to unsafe code, so thanks for the alternative method.

Comment: I will edit the question so that method is used intead of `SetWindowLongPtrW()`